# I am trying to create a macro that will allow me to Delete columns based on a checkbox

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, checkbox, countif

I am trying to create a macro that will allow me to click checkboxes, they are dynamic so there will always be a different number of columns and checkboxes (could be A:G but also could be A: AA).

The macro needs to first read to see if the "TRUE" value exists in Column A, then look at Column B's value, it would then match that text value to the respective text value in Row 1.
i.e., Reading and would NOT be deleted as A2 had been checked.

If it does not have a "TRUE" value, the respective column matching the adjacent cell in column B will be deleted.
i.e., there was not a "TRUE" value in A3, so Grammar column got deleted out of the row.

Attatched are my code, an example of my spreadsheet, and what I want it to look like after the code is run.

```
Sub Main_Routine()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim lr As range
Dim lc As range
Dim rng As range
Dim FindString As String
Dim lCell As range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Result")

Set lr = range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))

Set lc = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

For i = lc.Column To 3 Step -1
    If ((Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.range("A:A"), "TRUE")) And (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.range("B:B"), (Cells(lr, 2) = Cells(1, i).Value)))) Then
        Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Original dataset

[image: Original dataset]

Post Macro Dataset

[image: Post Macro Dataset]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all checkbox controls are associated with a linked cell in column A. The content in the column A cell could become invisible when you apply a white font color.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Main_Routine()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long
    Dim arrData
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Result")
    ' Get the last row
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Get the last column
    lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' Load data from column A:B
    arrData = ws.Range("A2:B" & lr).Value
    For i = lc To 3 Step -1
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrData)
            ' Subject matching
            If arrData(j, 2) = ws.Cells(1, i).Value Then
                ' Checkbox is checked
                If arrData(j, 1) Then ws.Columns(i).Delete
            End If
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

> [Add a check box or option button](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-check-box-or-option-button-form-controls-9f201e46-8f6b-4a9d-a320-f44b28088cb0?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [How to link checkboxes to cells](https://spreadsheeto.com/checkbox-excel/#linked)